# SharePoint sp-pnp-js clear/empty multi user field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Looking at examples provided here (https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items)

I was trying to clear (Update) multi user field it doesn't clear. What am I missing? I tried setting it to null or empty array both failed with a bad request.

```
                    pnp.sp.web
                    .lists.getByTitle('Agreements')
                    .items.getById(agreement.Id)
                    .update({
                        Notes: 'Notes go here..',
                        // Clear Multi User Approver Field.
                        CurrentApprover: { results: [] },
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        resolve({ result: true });
                    }).catch((e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of user field value, the field name should be referenced as `<UserFieldName>Id`. For example for a field with `CurrentApprover` name, the field should be referenced as  `CurrentApproverId`. This is the probably the reason why user field value is getting ignored while update in your case.

Updated example

```
pnp.sp.web
.lists.getByTitle('Agreements')
.items.getById(agreement.Id)
.update({
    Notes: 'Notes go here..',
    // Clear Multi User Approver Field.
    CurrentApproverId: { results: [] },
})
.then((result) => {
   resolve({ result: true });
}).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Yes, Thank you very much and nice catch!